# make a video player which is auto play from playlist using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to autoplay from a play list. When a song ends it should automatically play the next song in the play list. How can I do this? Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  projekktor('#player_a', {
      poster: 'media/intro.png',
      title: 'this is projekktor',
      playerFlashMP4: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
      playerFlashMP3: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
      width: 640,
      height: 385,
      enableTestcard: true,
      autoplay: true,
      playlist: [{
        0: {
          src: "1.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        1: {
          src: "2.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        3: {
          src: "3.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      }]
    }, function(player) {} // on ready 
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended to use a 3rd party jquery plugin

Example 
https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist

http://videojs.com/